# How to animate label in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to move my `label` from the top to the bottom and vice versa in jQuery.
I am using the following code:

```
$("#LabelId").animate({ top: "-=30px", width: "100%" }, 2500,"slow");

<label id="LabelId">Label</label>
```

But it's giving me an error while processing.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because of `2500` and `"slow"`are both duration methods, you got to chose one, not both. 2500 is 2.5 seconds and slow is a second or something i dont know the exact seconds for slow.

So do either

```
$("#LabelId").animate({ top: "-=30px", width: "100%" }, 2500);
```

or

```
$("#LabelId").animate({ top: "-=30px", width: "100%" }, "slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing through two duration arguments. You also need to give the label a `position` or a display property other than `inline`: Try this:

```
$("#LabelId").animate({ top: "-=30px", width: "100%" },'slow');
```

And add to your CSS:

```
#LabelId {
    position: relative;
}​
```

Please see a working demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/Z2vqe/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing px for top

```
$("#LabelId").animate({ top: '-=30', width: "100%" },'slow');
```

See the basic usage of animate with directional properties like top, left

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

AS and Always, **jQuery and CSS are context based**, you need to make sure about your context.

so if you want to make animation of label within parent control then you must specify css position to `position:relative;`. In case when you want to make it animate in document then specify to `position:absolute;`. and In case of  when you want to make it animate in window then specify to `position:static;.`

Again,jQuery will do the rest..`$("#LabelId").animate({ top: "-=30px", width: "100%" }, 2500);`